# Can PCI-e power limit be lower than 75W and will it affect RX460 performance?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, pci

I bought an MSI RX 460 4GB for my Lenovo H50 with 280W PSU. GPU-Z shows "board power limit" as 48W. I test and see GPU usage rise to 100% but power draw seems to stay at 48-50W. What does that mean? Do I have an option to raise it to 75W? Will I be able to utilize GPU to full extent at 48W or should I return it? Thanks.
Edit: i5-4460 (84W) I added 10W each for motherboard, drive and RAM. At 85% efficiency the total is below 280 so I thought PSU would be sufficient. Why doesn't the math work? :/

Comment: If the GPU is not under stress, e.g. a game at high frame rate and resolution, why would you expect the GPU to draw more power? A more practical test than to measure power draw is to see if you get satisfactory experience playing.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have an option to raise it to 75W?

No

> What does that mean?

It means your 280 Watt PSU is insufficient.

> Will I be able to utilize GPU to the full extent at 48W?

No

> Should I return it?

Only you can decide, if you want to return the product, I cannot help you make that decision.  I suggest simply, installing a 400 Watt PSU, so you are able to use your new GPU.

The `AMD A10-7800` consumes upwards of 110 Watts.  You need have to include any additional components you have installed, and you end up in a situation where your PSU is unable to provide enough power to all your components.  Even if you were to force the GPU to draw more power, your system would be unstable (i.e. it would randomly turn off), so you should simply replace the PSU.